# Which C# data structure allows searching a pair of strings most efficiently for substrings?

Tags: c#, .net, search, dictionary, substring

I have a data structure which consists of pairs of values, the first of which is an integer and the second of which is an alphanumeric string (which may begin with digits):

```
+--------+-----------------+
| Number | Name            |
+--------+-----------------+
| 15     | APPLES          |
| 16     | APPLE COMPUTER  |
| 17     | ORANGE          |
| 21     | TWENTY-1        |
| 291    | 156TH ELEMENT   |
+--------+-----------------+
```

A table of these would comprise up to 100,000 rows.

I'd like to provide a lookup function in which the user can look up either the number (as if it were a string), or pieces of the string. Ideally the lookup will be "live" as the user types; after each keystroke (or maybe after a brief delay ~250-500 ms) a new search will be done to find the most likely candidates. So, for example searching on

- `1` will return `15  APPLES`, `16  APPLE COMPUTER`, `17  ORANGE`, and
  `291  156TH ELEMENT`
- `15` will narrow the search to `15  APPLES`, `291  156TH ELEMENT`
- `AP` will return `15  APPLES` and `16  APPLE COMPUTER`
- (ideally, but not required) `ELEM` will return `291  156TH ELEMENT`.

I was thinking about using two `Dictionary<string, string>`s since ultimately the `int`s are being compared as `string`s -- one will index by the integer part and the other by the string part.

But really searching by substring shouldn't use a hash function, and it seems wasteful to use twice the memory that I feel like I should need.

Ultimately the question is, is there any well-performing way to text search two large lists simultaneously for substrings?

Failing that, how about a `SortedDictionary`? Might increase performance but still wouldn't solve the hash problem.

Thought about creating a regex on the fly, but I would think that would perform terribly.

I'm new to C# (having come from the Java world) so I haven't looked into LINQ yet; is that the answer?

**EDIT 18:21 EST**: None of the strings in the "Name" field will be longer than 12-15 characters, if that affects your potential solution.

Comment: I think a slightly modified implementation of the [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) would be useful.

Comment: When you say "efficiently" do you mean "quickly" or least memory?  Generally in these scenarios you trade speed for memory, or find some acceptable balance of the two.  Also are 100k string fairly static, meaning there is little turnover and they are searched repeatedly?

Comment: @EBarr: Memory isn't a huge concern, but I don't want to be wasteful. Speed is more important here.

Comment: So if the user enters "comp" would you want "16 APPLE COMPUTER" to display? If matches can be inside the string like that, the approach will be quite different than if you only want to match against the beginning of the values in your table.

Comment: +1 for the (uncommon) correct use of "comprise"

Comment: @Tenner - what about stability of the strings?  frequency of searches?  Also, to @/hatchet's point can you match (a) anchored to the start of the string, (b) start of word boundaries, or (c) anywhere?

Comment: @hatchet: That condition would be covered under my "optional" case. It would be nice if performance allowed, but I can sacrifice that search condition if no solution performs adequately.

Comment: @EBarr: Start of the string is required; start of word boundaries would be nice but not required; and I would only support "anywhere" if more than a couple characters were entered. There are too many options otherwise and the user would be overwhelmed. Also, if it matters, none of the strings will be longer than 12-15 characters, so we're not talking about searching a large amount of text in each row.

Comment: @EBarr: Regarding stability, the strings will be fairly stable throughout the life of the application, but I may need to make a few additions/modifications/deletions throughout the application. If I can search for an item I'll assume I can also modify it or delete it easily.

Comment: I must be missing something here, because I don't see why you're going through the hassle of searching two different sources. Would it be possible to concatenate a key/value item to a single item (ie - "15 Apples", "16 Apple Compter") and jam all of them into a list<string>, and then search upon that list?

Comment: @Jagd: I could do that, but that requires true substring search (which may be too inefficient to implement here). I'd also then have to know to prefer searches on the first characters of name over other instances. For example, searching for `COMP`, `9385 COMPUTER SALES` would be preferred over `16 APPLE COMPUTER`. That could be done using some kind of comparator, however, once the list has been winnowed to a much smaller number of candidates.

Comment: Ah, I see. Weighted results based upon business rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd consider using [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure.

How to achieve that? Leaves would represent your "row", but you would have "two paths" to each memory instance of a "row" (one for number and the other one for name).

You can then sacrifice your condition:

```
(ideally, but not required) ELEM will return 291 156TH ELEMENT.
```

Or provide even more paths to your row instances.

Comment: Interesting; I'll certainly look into implementing this and see how well it performs. I didn't include this fact in the original post but I can probably do the initial tree-creation at program start; if that takes a little extra time that's certainly not the end of the world. Thanks!

Comment: Spot on here.  Beat me to the punch ;-)

Comment: It's more "a wicked" solution than "an optimal one in terms of memory usage". It's the one that makes you weep like a child when you implement it :) As mentioned by Phil, Lucene.Net is a good solution, but it really depends on your specific use case. 100k of such strings ... that's ~1MB probably. Not much really if you have them available right there in memory, but it you would need to pull them from the database many times on request and build a trie first, then that's another story.

Comment: It's likely that the trie could be constructed when a file is opened or when the application is first opened and kept in memory. It's possible that a user will use this particular search many times throughout the course of the day. I may also be able to put in some kind of simple garbage-collection myself if the user doesn't use the search for more than a certain amount of time, and rebuild the trie on demand when necessary.

Comment: I think a variation of this will be the winner. I'm working out writing an implementation of a radix trie which will carry the benefit of a payload available at each node of the trie. The payload will carry a reference to the object represented by this string. This will also allow entries which share a common beginning like "APPLE" and "APPLESAUCE" to point to different entities. Additionally, the number part and name part will have their own trie paths and will both point to the same underlying object since they  represent the same object. Thanks all!

Answer (score 6):

If possible, I would avoid loading all 100,000 entries into memory.  I would use either a database or [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) to index the values. Then use the appropriate query syntax to efficiently search for the results.

Comment: What I've outlined above is a very small part of the product, and I'd really prefer the lightest-weight solution possible. That said, I'll certainly consider Lucene.net in-memory if I can't come up with anything else that performs well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are searching for the beginning of words, key based collections will not work, unless you store all possible pieces of the words, like "a", "ap", "app", "appl", "apple".

My suggestion is to use a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` in conjunction with a binary search. You would have to provide your own `IComparer<T>`, which also finds the beginning of words. You would use two data structures.

One `List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>` holding single words or the number as key and the number as value.

One `Dictionary<int,string>` holding the whole name.

You would proceed like this:

1. Split your sentence (the whole name) into single words.
2. Add them to the list with the word as key and the number as value of the `KeyValuePair`.
3. Add the number to the list as key and as value of the `KeyValuePair`.
4. When the list is full, sort the list in order to allow a binary search.

Search for a beginning of a word:

1. Search in the list by using `BinarySearch` in conjunction with your `IComparer<T>`.
2. The index you get from the search might not be the first that applies, so go back in the list until you find the first entry that matches.
3. Using the number stored as value in the list, look up the whole name in the dictionary using this number as key.